# How to compare a variable in PHP and change CSS depending on result

Tags: php, css

How can I test if the value of a PHP variable equals a number, and then change an element's css on that number.

Comment: change class of the object on this value of variable.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that PHP is executed on the server, generating the page, you could use something like this :

```
<?php if ($variable == 10) : ?>
    <p class="firstclass">plop !</p>
<?php else : ?>
    <p class="otherclass">plop !</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or, using the condition to only change the CSS class :

```
<p class="<?php echo $variable == 10 ? 'firstclass' : 'otherclass'; ?>">plop !</p>
```

Comment: Is there a name for PHP syntax like these examples? I always assumed `if` statements were enclosed in `{}` and I've never seen the second example before, ty.

Comment: That's an HTML class, not a CSS class.

Comment: @Daniel see http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php ; that alternative syntax is often used in templates, when mixing PHP and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `is_numeric()` and a `switch()` statement to output the CSS number if it is inline.  If your CSS is not inline, you can use separate classes and change the class.

Link -
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the CSS is in a different file. You can use PHP to dynamically generate CSS. Instead of using style.css you use style.php and include the code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");
?>
```

At the beginning of the file. This tells the user that this file is to be treated as a style sheet. This allows you to send data to the stylesheet. For instance, you use GET to to send a color code for a specific element. You use PHP on the HTML page to make a stylesheet link to style.php?color=#FFFFFF and in the stylesheet you use this:

```
element {
color: <?php echo $_GET["color"];?> ;
}
```

If this doesn't work, let me know.